# adding class to this href .. not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have uplaod function on our site. And uploaded file, displays link which on click user can see file they have uploaded in new window.

We also use divbox http://jquery.phpbasic.com/divbox

My code is this:

```
$("#uploader" + queueId).html("
 <div class='cancel'>
  <input class='button_cancel' name='removeFile' fileName='"
  +fileObj.name.replace("'", "%27")+"' type='button'>
   </div>
  <a class='lightbox' href='" + self.attr("path") 
   + fileObj.name.replace("'", "%27") + "'><span class='fileName'>"
+fileObj.name+"</span></a>");
```

For some reason when we click on the link, it still opens in new window and doesnt initiate the lightbox.

In my page i see this ( all normal )

```
<a class="lightbox" href="uploads/nutshell.png">
 <span class="fileName">nutshell.png</span>
</a>
```

Which should fire the lightbox.. Anything scream out at you in the js code I posted above ? I am wondering if its self.attr("path")

Here is what we have::::::

in the js for divbox we have

```
$('.lightbox').divbox({caption: false});
```

in the js for the uploader we have.

```
$("#uploader" + queueId).html("<div class='cancel'><input class='button_cancel' name='removeFile' fileName='"+fileObj.name.replace("'", "%27")+"' type='button'></div><a class='lightbox' href='" + self.attr("path") + fileObj.name.replace("'", "%27") + "'><span class='fileName'>"+fileObj.name+"</span></a>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're doing something like this:

```
$('a.lightbox').divbox({ ... })
```

*before* you add the `<a>` in question with:

```
$("#uploader" + queueId).html("...");
```

`$('a.lightbox')` only applies to elements that exist on the page when `$('a.lightbox')` is called, it won't bind DivBox to elements that are added to the page later. You'll have to bind DivBox to the new `<a>` that you added with something like this:

```
$("#uploader" + queueId).html("...");
$('#uploader' + queueId).find('a.lightbox').divbox({ /* and whatever options you need */ });
```

Rough demo of the technique: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EswfB/

Comment: apologies for delay. Had to shoot out. In the divbox js I have, $('.lightbox').divbox({caption: false}); code for the uploader js is : $("#uploader" + queueId).html("<div class='cancel'><input class='button_cancel' name='removeFile' fileName='"+fileObj.name.replace("'", "%27")+"' type='button'></div><a class='lightbox' href='" + self.attr("path") + fileObj.name.replace("'", "%27") + "'><span class='fileName'>"+fileObj.name+"</span></a>");

Comment: @422: Sorry about the lightbox vs divbox confusion, should have been `lightbox` in your case (the examples use `divbox`, hence my confusion). The point is that you're probably binding the DivBox and then adding new things to the DOM later.

Comment: Hi Mu yeah I get that, I just dont know how to bind lightbox to the event after divbox.js has loaded. Your sample looks promising.. but no idea how to implement the code...

Comment: @422: After you add the new HTML with `$("#uploader" + queueId).html(...)`, you find the the newly added `<a class="lightbox">` inside it with `$('#uploader' + queueId).find('a.lightbox')` and then bind the divbox to it.

Comment: If i uploaded sample to slave domain do you think you could assist further Mu ?

Comment: excellent, but way way over my head lol. WIll choose your answer, even though I have no blinkin idea how to use it. Cheers for your help anyway mate

Answer (score 1):

To build off of mu is too short's answer, you could implement like so:

```
$("#uploader" + queueId).html("
 <div class='cancel'>
  <input class='button_cancel' name='removeFile' fileName='"+fileObj.name.replace("'", "%27")+"' type='button'>
 </div>
 <a class='lightbox' href='" + self.attr("path") 
   + fileObj.name.replace("'", "%27") + "'><span class='fileName'>"
   +fileObj.name+"</span></a>")
   .find('a.lightbox')
   .divbox({ /* and whatever options you need */ });
```

And simply chain the commands into one.

Comment: what i dont get is /* and whatever options you need */ whats that about ?

Comment: the divbox method takes arguments. for fictional example $('.lightbox').divbox({width: 200, opacity: 0.9})

Comment: Yer we finally managed it. The issue seemed to stem from what Mu was saying in that binding the event after dom has loaded. All good thanks for your efforts.